# Multidimensional array with unknown size

Tags: java, arrays, kryonet

I need to create an array with an undefined size, which will contain user information.

For example:

```
user[0]["name"] = "Patrick";
```

However, the standard java array seems to require a known length, which I don't know.

What alternative can i use? (I'll gladly see some coding examples as well)  I'm using a TCP framework ([kryonet](/questions/tagged/kryonet)) which doesn't allow to pass objects with constructors. Therefore, as far as i can see, making a User object is not possible.

Comment: You might store an `ArrayList<Person>` where `Person` contains attribute `name`.

Comment: Just a note, kryonet DOES allow you to pass objects with constructors, it just requires that there be an empty () constructor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java we can only use integer values for cell indexes.

I guess you're looking for a list of maps:

```
List<Map<String, String>> persons = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

// add Patrick
Map<String, String> person = new HashMap<String, String>();
person.put("name", "Patrick");
person.put("age", "23");
persons.add(person);

// add Sue
person = new HashMap<String, String>();
person.put("name", "Sue");
person.put("age", "21");
persons.add(person);
```

To access all names, for instance:

```
for (Map<String, String> person:persons) {
  System.out.println(person.get("name"));
}
```

Comment: This is definitely what i need. However, i can't add multiple persons, it just overwrites the others. How do i add multiple persons to this? :-)

Comment: Each person "is a" map in the list. Simply create a new map for each new person and add it to the list (persons). I've added Patrick in the last line.

Comment: I can't get it working. Could you possibly expand your example to include a second person?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should use Objects instead of arbitary data structures and if you don't know the size, I would use a List

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Patrick"));
```

Comment: The problem is, my Player class have a constructor, which the TCP framework i'm using (Kryonet) doesn't allow to be sent

Comment: You can't send any object, even a String object over TCP.  You have to serialize/encode it in some manner. I would define your class as it should and serialize it as a seperate consideration.

Comment: I ment the frameworks serializer can't handle objects with constructors :-)

Comment: There are ways to fix this in the framework (I assume this is not an option), but usually frameworks only require you have a public constructor, not that it be your only constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use associative arrays in java. In other words, you cannot use "name" as a key.

But you can create empty arrays without specifying size by doing:

```
String[] array = new String[]{};
```

However, attempting to put something into this array will give you an indexoutofbound exception

Answer (score 0):

You should consider create a class (like Person) and use only a List to manage it. The you could do something like this:

```
List<Peson> myLyst = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person person = new Person("Patrick");
myList.add(0, person);
```